# NHibernate One-To-Many Using A Join Table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is this possible without mapping the join table to a domain entity?

For example if I have the following three tables, account and note are joined by the table account_note.  Can i map a collection of notes to account class with a one to many mapping?

```
1   to   M  |  1    to  M
```

Account -> Account_Note -> Note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `many-to-many` element.

Example:

```
<class name="Account">
  <id .../>
  <bag name="Notes" table="Account_Note">
    <key column="AccountId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Note" column="NoteId"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found some forum posts about it on nhforge. I noticed you used a bag, I've been told by some to always use bags, do you?

Comment: I used bag as an example, but you can use whatever fits your domain (bag, set, list...)